# Thin Plate Regression Spline Problem

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines

I fitted a Thin Plate Regression Spline into some non-linear relationships and I get good results, but I had problems in the tails of the distributions.

Someone knows what could be the cause of this problem in the tails of the distribution? Or where I can find some paper or book to explain this thing?

Thanks for your time. 
Have a nice day